# Ansible variable substitution issues in JSON file

Tags: json, ansible

I have a JSON file with the user details using which I want to create a user. It all works fine if everything in JSON is plain text. However I want to keep the password in the Ansible vault and read it from there in to my JSON. However when I load the file, the variable is not being substituted with the password. I can print the password variable which printed the password in plain text.

I need to supply user details as a JSON object to one of the API which creates the user with that info. My password is in the ansible vault. I have a variable with the ansible hash for this password. My JSON file looks as below.

```
{"Users":
        [
            {  
              "databaseName" : "admin",
              "roles" : [ {    
                "databaseName" : "admin",
                "roleName" : "readAnyDatabase"
              } ],
              "username" : "AnsibleReadUser",
              "password" : "{{ apikey }}"
            },
            {  
              "databaseName" : "admin",
              "roles" : [ {    
                "databaseName" : "admin",
                "roleName" : "readWriteAnyDatabase"
              } ],
              "username" : "AnsibleReadWriteUser",
              "password" : "{{ apikey }}"
            }
        ]
}
```

Here is my ansible task to load the JSON file.

```
- name: Load Input files
  set_fact:
    userinfo_json: "{{ lookup('file', 'UserDetails.json') | from_json }}"
```

When I print the content of 'userinfo_json' the variable is not substituted.

```
 "msg": "UserDetails JSON: {'Users': [{'databaseName': 'admin', 'roles': [{'databaseName': 'admin', 'roleName': 'readAnyDatabase'}], 'username': 'AnsibleReadUser', 'password': '{{ apikey }}'}, {'databaseName': 'admin', 'roles': [{'databaseName': 'admin', 'roleName': 'readWriteAnyDatabase'}], 'username': 'AnsibleReadWriteUser', 'password': '{{ apikey }}'}]}"
}
```

I want the {{ apikey }}' to be replaced with the variable value.

```
{"Users":
        [
            {  
              "databaseName" : "admin",
              "roles" : [ {    
                "databaseName" : "admin",
                "roleName" : "readAnyDatabase"
              } ],
              "username" : "AnsibleReadUser",
              "password" : "Password"
            },
            {  
              "databaseName" : "admin",
              "roles" : [ {    
                "databaseName" : "admin",
                "roleName" : "readWriteAnyDatabase"
              } ],
              "username" : "AnsibleReadWriteUser",
              "password" : "Password"
            }
        ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Neither `lookup('file', ...` nor the filter (`from_yaml` works for me, `from_jason` failed) does not expand the variables

```
  vars:
    apikey: my-secret-apikey
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        userinfo_json: "{{ lookup('file', 'UserDetails.json') | from_yaml }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ userinfo_json.Users|json_query('[*].password') }}"
```

The tasks above give

```
"msg": [
    "{{ apikey }}", 
    "{{ apikey }}"
]
```

Use [include_vars](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/include_vars_module.html#include-vars-load-variables-from-files-dynamically-within-a-task) instead

```
  vars:
    apikey: my-secret-apikey  # replace with vault encrypted variable
  tasks:
    - name: Load Input files
      include_vars:
        file: UserDetails.json
        name: userinfo_json
    - debug:
        var: userinfo_json
```

This gives

```
"userinfo_json": {
    "Users": [
        {
            "databaseName": "admin", 
            "password": "my-secret-apikey", 
            "roles": [
                {
                    "databaseName": "admin", 
                    "roleName": "readAnyDatabase"
                }
            ], 
            "username": "AnsibleReadUser"
        }, 
        {
            "databaseName": "admin", 
            "password": "my-secret-apikey", 
            "roles": [
                {
                    "databaseName": "admin", 
                    "roleName": "readWriteAnyDatabase"
                }
            ], 
            "username": "AnsibleReadWriteUser"
        }
    ]
}
```

Note. `name: userinfo_json` is not necessary. If you omit this parameter the list of users will be stored in the variable `Users`.

The same result can be achieved with [vars_files](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#defining-variables-in-files)

```
  vars:
    apikey: my-secret-apikey
  vars_files:
    - UserDetails.json
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: Users
```

Q: "`I was trying to load two files as below. But only anotherfileinfo_json has the json content and userinfo_json is empty.`"

```
- include_vars:
    file: UserDetails.json
    name: userinfo_json
    file: AnotherFile.json
    name: anotherfileinfo_json
```

A: Looking at the [Examples](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/include_vars_module.html#examples) the task below should work

```
  - include_vars: "{{ lookup('file', my_files) }}"
    vars:
      my_files:
        - UserDetails.json
        - AnotherFile.json
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I ended up using include_vars for my issue. However I tried not use the name: userinfo_json but the Users was null. So I kept it as is since I need to extract more info in my other tasks from this variable. In fact I was trying to load two files as below ```include_vars:
        file: UserDetails.json
        name: userinfo_json
        file: AnotherFile.json
        name: anotherfileinfo_json ```. But only anotherfileinfo_json has the json content and userinfo_json is empty.

Answer (score 1):

> I want the {{ apikey }}' to be replaced with the variable value.

Then you will need to use the [`template`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.8/plugins/lookup/template.html) lookup, not `file`; `file` just reads in the literal text

You will also want to use extreme caution when doing string substitution into a JSON file, **especially** password strings, since jinja2 does not know that your document is JSON. Thus, a password of `abc"def` will render into your document as `"password": "abc"def"` which is invalid. There are a number of techniques to work around that problem, and maybe they don't apply to you since it's an "apikey" (according to your variable names) but just be aware.

Comment: I have gone through templates. If I understand you correctly, I need to do the opposite of what I am trying to do. Rather than starting with a JSON file and substitute variables in it; using templates create a new JSON file every time I run the tasks along with the variable substitution. Please correct me if I misunderstood you. If that is the case, isn't my vault secured password visible in the resultant JSON file until I delete it? I wish there is a way to substitute the variables in memory and pass that JSON to my API call.

Comment: I have used templates and solved this problem.` - name: Load Atlas config file  
  set_fact:  
    clusterinfo_json: "{{ lookup('template', './templates/atlasconfig.j2') }}"` and my template files looks like this. `{
  "name" : "{{ mongoclustername }}",
  "providerSettings" : {
    "providerName" : "AZURE",    
    "regionName" : "{{ mongoclusterregion }}",
    "instanceSizeName" : "{{ mongoclusterinstancesize }}"
  },  
  "backupEnabled" : false,
  "diskGBEnabled" : false
}`